# How to draw subgraph using networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I try to draw subgraph from karate_club_graph in networkx based on a list of nodes'name but failed. How could draw subgraph as I want to show?

```
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib import pylab as pl

G = nx.karate_club_graph()
res = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
new_nodes = []
for n in G.nodes(data=True):
  if n[0] in res:
    new_nodes.append(n)

k = G.subgraph(new_nodes)
pos = nx.spring_layout(k)

pl.figure()
nx.draw(k, pos=pos)
pl.show()
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem you're having is that your subgraph command is telling it to make a subgraph with a nodelist where each element is not just the node name, but also the data about that node name.  The command `G.subgraph` needs just the list of node names.

The easiest way to fix this is just

```
k = G.subgraph(res)
```

which will work even if some of the nodes in `res` aren't in `G`.

I'll do this change and also show how to draw several times with consistent positions by adding an additional subgraph to plot.  It will plot your `k` and then the subgraph made up of all nodes not in `k`.  Note that no edges will exist between the two because of how `subgraph` works.

```
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib import pylab as pl

G = nx.karate_club_graph()
res = [0,1,2,3,4,5, 'parrot'] #I've added 'parrot', a node that's not in G
                              #just to demonstrate that G.subgraph is okay
                              #with nodes not in G.    
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)  #setting the positions with respect to G, not k.
k = G.subgraph(res)  

pl.figure()
nx.draw_networkx(k, pos=pos)

othersubgraph = G.subgraph(range(6,G.order()))
nx.draw_networkx(othersubgraph, pos=pos, node_color = 'b')
pl.show()
```

### [image]

The effect of having `data=True` in the `G.nodes()` call is as follows:

```
print G.nodes()
> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33]
print G.nodes(data=True)
> [(0, {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}), (1, {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}), (2, {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}), (3, {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}), (4, {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}), (5, {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}), (6, {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}), (7, {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}) ...  *I've snipped stuff out*
```

So `G.nodes()` just gives the node names.  `G.nodes(data=True)` gives a list of tuples, which have node name as the first entry and a dict showing any data about those nodes in the second entry.

Comment: Can you tell me what does it mean when and why to set data=true?

Comment: I've edited the answer to explain it.  Basically having `data=True` means that it also provides any data that the graph has stored about the nodes.

Comment: I have another question: Actually I would like to realize that subgraph shows the chosen nodes from original graph while their locations remains same compared to original graph; but by this way above I observe that the shape and locations of the subgraph already changed. Do you have any idea to realize such effect?

Comment: Do `pos=nx.spring_layout(G)`.  Then `pos` is a dict such that `pos[u]` gives the `x,y` coordinates of node `u`.  Then when you draw `k`, use this position dict.

Comment: And finally - I've just checked that `G.subgraph(res)` works even if some of the nodes in `res` aren't in `G`.